# 1 test fail during perl make test

Tags: perl, installation

I'm trying to install Perl-5.8.3 on RHEL4U9.

At the end of 'make test', it indicates 1 test is failed.  How do I fix it to make it passes all tests? Or should I just ignore it?

```
Failed Test               Stat Wstat Total Fail  Failed  List of Failed
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
../lib/File/Find/t/find.t              189    5   2.65%  161 173 183-184 189
55 tests and 345 subtests skipped.
```

Output of prove -v:

```
# prove -v ../lib/File/Find/t/find.t
../lib/File/Find/t/find....Perl lib version (v5.8.3) doesn't match executable version (v5.8.8) at ../lib/Config.pm line 32.
Compilation failed in require at ../lib/File/Find.pm line 1223.
Compilation failed in require at ../lib/File/Find/t/find.t line 48.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ../lib/File/Find/t/find.t line 50.
dubious
        Test returned status 255 (wstat 65280, 0xff00)
FAILED--1 test script could be run, alas--no output ever seen
```

Comment: Run the failing test file with `prove -v` to see *why* it's failing.  With only this information, nobody can tell you anything more.

Comment: Please provide the output from that test.

Comment: nm, they don't provide meaningful output.